# Uber Api Error : The rider's payment method is invalid and they must update their billing info

Tags: uber-api

I tried to integrate uber to my app. Create an app and I reached the level of request a ride.

i tried to request a ride by using following post method:

https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests?access_token=

then getting an error like

```
{
"meta": {},
"errors": [
    {
        "status": 400,
        "code": "invalid_payment",
        "title": "The rider's payment method is invalid and they must update their billing info."
    }
]
}
```

in my uber account added all the payment methods( cash, paytm, debit card),
Is required to keep minimum balance in my paytm or debit card to book a ride?

how can i solve this??

thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Can you please supply full request to the "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests" endpoint?. Do not supply access_tiken - just want to see what is your parameter list? Are you using : "payment_method_id" parameter?

Comment: i am just using https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests link and add access token in header. in the body session added {"product_id": "821415d8-3bd5-4e27-9604-194e4359a449", "start_latitude" : 37.775232, "start_longitude" : -122.4197513,"end_latitude" : 37.7899886, "end_longitude" : -122.4021253,"fare_id" : b523c4b049ec39966c0fc407dfa1a4c009089372e012d11623cdfd23edcc6a44"} these details

Answer (score 1):

From your request, I'm not sure what payment method you were using. You have an option to get a list of all payment methods by using following API "[GET /v1.2/payment-methods](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/payment-methods-get)". So response looks like:

> `Status-Code: 200 OK` {   "payment_methods": [
>       {
>         "payment_method_id": "5f384f7d-8323-4207-a297-51c571234a8c",
>         "type": "baidu_wallet",
>         "description": "*53",
>       },
>       {
>         "payment_method_id": "f33847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c",
>         "type": "alipay",
>         "description": "ga***@uber.com",
>       },
>       {
>         "payment_method_id": "**f43847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c**",
>         "type": "visa",
>         "description": "***23"
>       },
>       {
>         "payment_method_id": "517a6c29-3a2b-45cb-94a3-35d679909a71",
>         "type": "american_express",
>         "description": "***05"
>       },
>       {
>         "payment_method_id": "f53847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c",
>         "type": "business_account",
>         "description": "Late Night Ride"
>       }   ],
>      "last_used": "f53847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c" }

There you can find payment method ID - and you can use it when you create your ride request.

Example:

> {
>   "fare_id":"d30e732b8bba22c9cdc10513ee86380087cb4a6f89e37ad21ba2a39f3a1ba9",
>     "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
>       **"payment_method_id": "f43847de-8113-4587-c307-51c2d13a823c"**
>           "start_latitude": 37.761492,
>       "start_longitude": -122.423941,
>     "end_latitude": 37.775393,
>       "end_longitude": -122.417546
>      }

Comment: Thank you very much, i wil try this and let u know

Comment: i just replace my link with https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests?access_token=<access token>, then i get responses:)